# Android: при обновлении контент провидера дергается экран и слетает прокрутка в самый верх списка.

Tags: android, contentprovider, java, сокет

Здравствуйте! Появилась такая неприятная проблема: у меня реализовано обновление `ListFragment` через контент-провидер. По сокету приходят данные, я заношу их в базу и уведомляю контент-провидер о том что данные изменились. На экране в этот момент происходит  подергивание списка, а если я находился в самом низу списка, то меня меня перебрасывает в самый верх списка (такое ощущение что он не обновляет адаптер, а перестраивает его полностью). Хотя подобные действия в приложении `Trello` (там тоже по сокету обновления приходят) происходят очень спокойно и без подергиваний и сброса прокрутки.

Я даже не пойму, в какой части всего механизма искать решение проблемы...

1. [`NotificationsContentProvider`](http://pastebin.com/HTAjZbpE)
2. [`CirclesContentProvider`](http://pastebin.com/JRCujXmf)

В сокете идет разбор уведомления и потом сохраняется:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("_id", notification.id);
cv.put("messages_count", notification.messages_count);
cv.put("create_date", notification.create_date);
cv.put("model_name", notification.model_name);
cv.put("sphere_id", notification.sphere_id);
cv.put("circle_id", notification.circle_id);
cv.put("dt", notification.dt); mContext.getContentResolver().insert(NotificationsContentProvider.NOTIFICATION_CONTENT_URI, cv);
```

UPD.1 : Есть успехи. Дерганье возникает при обновлении двух контент провидеров в классе `NotificationsContentProvider`. Если на строках 88-89 сделать так:

```
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(resultUri, null);
//getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(CirclesContentProvider.CIRCLE_CONTENT_URI, null);
```

то дергаться перестает, но мне всё же жизненно необходимо уведомить `CirclesContentProvider` о том, что данные в `NotificationsContentProvider` изменились...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну так хотя бы код обновления адаптера показали.....

Вместо

```
adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
```

попробуйте

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```