# Android: синхронизация NavigationDrawer и основного контента

Tags: android, contentprovider, java, сокет

Здравствуйте! По мотивам [**вопроса**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/302322/java-android-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0) хочу узнать, может я неправильно что-то делаю?

Есть такая схема:

[image]

В тот момента, когда я обновляю `CirclesCP` из `NotificationsCP` на экране происходит дерганье и скрол списка улетает наверх.

Обновление `CirclesCP` нужно, что бы изменились счетчики количества уведомлений в каждом круге:

[image]

Comment: вот код то мы не видим. то что у вас работает по схеме одно, а как вот написано - это другое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена: в методе `onLoadFinished` после обновления курсора, у меня вызывался метод, который перестраивал фрагмент с основным контентов, вот поэтому всё дергалось и прокрутка слетала наверх.